# C - Writing on second line of file

Tags: c, file

Im doing the Hangman game on C and I have a trouble on one of the txt files.
I'm trying to append "num_letters" on the second line of the file.My code prints on new line everytime I guess. Is there a "lightweight" way to skip the first line and append on the second one?

```
  void write_stats(int tries, int num_letters)
{
    FILE *stats;
    stats = fopen("C:\\Users\\rjmal\\Documents\\CLION PROJECTS\\JogoDaForca\\stats.txt", "a");
    fprintf(stats," %d",tries);
    fprintf(stats,"\n %d",num_letters);
    fclose(stats);
}
```

Comment: Try this: `fprintf(stats,"\r\n%d",tries);`

Comment: @ProXicT: Don't add cariage return manually! Windows opens files by default in text-mode and applies a newline-filter anyway. Your line will generate `\r\r\n` in the output. (And modern systems don't use `\r` anyway).

Comment: If the file has more than 2 lines: no. If it has just 2 lines, and the second line has no `newline` (which the last line in a text file does not need), what you have should work.

Comment: @Olaf: I know modern systems don't use `\r`, however, I didn't know Windows will deal with it like that, thanks for letting me know :)
I am developing on Linux..

Comment: The major reason for adding the "t" mode for `fopen` were actually DOS-based systems. Windows might not be DOS-based anymore, but it still (and will) suffer from its inheritance - needless to say I don't use Windows either. Linux/POSIX will just ignore the `t` parameter.

Comment: @ProXicT wont that add a newline everytime I save something?

Comment: @xmitz: Every time you will call the given function, it will append new line to the file specified.

Comment: @ProXicT I dont want to append a new line, I want to append on the 2nd line. Im sorry if I didnt express myself correcty on the question

Comment: @xmitz: How many bytes does the file usually have? If I get that right now, you want to put some text on the second line of the file, no matter how many lines does the file have?

Comment: @ProXicT what I want to do is, on the first line I want the "tries" and on the 2nd line I want the number of letters of the word. Basicly, two lines with int numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
/* Compiles with: gcc main.c -o test -pedantic -Wall -Wextra */
#include <stdio.h>

int write_stats(const int tries, const int num_letters, FILE* file) {
  if (!file)
    return -1;
  const int written = fprintf(file, "%d\n%d", tries, num_letters);
  if (written < 0)
    return -1;
  return 0;
}

int read_stats(int* tries, int* num_letters, FILE* file) {
  if (!file)
    return -1;

  if (fscanf(file, "%d\n%d", tries, num_letters) != 2)
    return -1;
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  /* writing stats */
  FILE* w_stats = fopen("stats.dat", "w");
  if (!w_stats) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open the file specified!\n");
    return 1;
  }
  if (write_stats(3, 8, w_stats) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Problem occoured while writing stats!\n");
    fclose(w_stats);
    return 1;
  }
  fclose(w_stats);

  /* reading the stats */
  FILE* r_stats = fopen("stats.dat", "r");
  if (!r_stats) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open the file specified!\n");
    return 1;
  }
  int tries, num_letters;
  if (read_stats(&tries, &num_letters, r_stats) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Problem occoured while reading stats!\n");
    fclose(r_stats);
    return 1;
  }
  fclose(r_stats);
  printf("tries: %d, num_letters: %d\n", tries, num_letters);

  return 0;
}
```

Hopefully it makes sense, I think this does not need any further explanation, since the code explains it itself. However, if you want to clarify something, feel free to ask.